# jQuery show on <a> tag on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

This works on Chrome and Firefox, but not on mobile Safari. I'm trying to simple show an img when a link is clicked. jQuery 1.10.1

HTML

```
<h1>Region</h1> <img src="/static/img/ajax-loader.gif" class="loading" />
<hr>
<div class="list-group">
    <a onclick="clickMe()" class="list-group-item" href="/feedback/studio/110/">Colorado <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickMe() {
    $('.loading').show();
}
</script>
```

CSS

```
.loading {
    display: none;
}
```

The img does not show when the link is clicked. The image DOES show if I change the href to "#" to test. The image IS VISIBLE if I just go back in the browser after following the link, but of course I'm trying to get it to show when the link is clicked.

Am I missing something simple to get this working on mobile Safari?

Comment: You need to prevent default anchor click behaviour but then what result are you expecting of setting it href attribute targeting other page???  Maybe delay redirection to let `.loading` animation enough time to show. But sounds like you want to use some ajax logic there. EDIT: if it doesn't work on Safari mobile, this is because of how this browser handles javascript execution on page redirection, blocking any useless script execution

Comment: I want to link to the other page but show the loading when the link is clicked as the next page makes some API calls and does some calculations so it takes a few seconds to load.

Comment: So try to prevent default behaviour and delay redirection using e.g a timeout to let UI enough time to be redraw. Not sure it will work as expected on Safari mobile though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try that:

Firstly, remove inline `onclick` attribute

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="/feedback/studio/110/">Colorado <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a>
```

bind event using, e.g, jQuery and prevent default behaviour and delay
   a little redirection: {i'm delegating it to `document` level so you
   are sure this event will be fired whenever/wherever you set it}

```
$(document).on('click', '.list-group-item', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var self = this;
     setTimeout(function(){
         window.location = self.href;
     },250);
});
```